# Unable to return data from php to react

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs

Hello whenever I am trying to return data from php to react component, I am getting this error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'http://localhost/loginpage/src/components/login.php' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3005' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Login.js:25
>
> > > Error: Network Error
> > >         at createError (createError.js:17)
> > >         at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)

when I use `echo` then I am getting data but not from a `return` or `print_r` statements.

I am using SQL as query language and axios for sending request.

Method used:

```
handleClick(event){
  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/loginpage/src/components/login.php',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    data: this.state
  })
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });

    }
```

and my php file is

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), TRUE);

$username = $data['username'];
$password = $data['password'];

$host = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'users';
$user= 'root';
$pass = '';
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass);

// Checking connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$conn->select_db("userss");

$result = "SELECT * FROM UserDetail WHERE email='$username' AND password='$password';";

$datas = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $a = {
            id:$row["id"],
            fname:$row["firstname"],
            lname:$row["lastname"],
            email:$row["email"]
        }
        array_push($datas, $a);
    }
    print_r($datas);
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I don't know how to use CORS so please give me a answer in code form that i can use or with which i can replace my code.
Anyone please provide a good solution. I am new to react.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: `$a = {id: $row['id'], ...}` isn't valid PHP syntax. That's how you build objects in JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: please provide an answer in code form as I don't have much idea about the answer you are saying my question is duplicate of.

Comment: Then you need to firstly read the duplicate a bit more, and try to understand it. You can also read about CORS in lots of other places online. Otherwise you'll carry on making the same mistake. Now the question is closed unfortunately no one can add a code answer. Make sure you understand what a preflight request is, and ensure your server is handling it appropriately - all the CORS headers need to be present on that request as well as the main one

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please forget this. this is way i was trying it by different methods so code left. It's not returning even a simple "Hello"

Comment: atleast the things I am doing wrong.

Comment: The thing is why I am getting data with echo . If it's a CORS issue I should not get even by echo. But I am getting